# Reaction mechanism of redox reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox

So on the data, it said that we can reduce potassium permanganate by utilizing oxalic acid, thus producing carbon dioxide.
But can anyone propose a reaction mechanism of how the whole reaction happens, and how did oxalic acid break up into $\ce{CO2}$?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I think it would go through a manganese-oxalate complex (oxalate is a good ligand for many metals), and that would fragment via a reaction such as:

[image: cyclic fragmentation of a manganese (VII) oxalate complex]

The Mn(V) species would likely disproportionate to manganese dioxide and permanganate.

Comment: Couldn't understand can you do a more formal explanation ?Thanks a lot!

Comment: More formally, the complex shown results from adding oxalic acid to permanganate ion with elimination of a water molecule. The three curly arrows each represent a pair of electrons moving to shift the pattern of bonding from reactants to products. The result is a change of oxidation state (REDUCTION) of manganese from VII to V. Hope this helps!

Comment: But wouldn't the result became Mn (II) ion?

Comment: Either that or manganese (IV) dioxide, depending on pH and other factors--as a final result. But other intermediate oxidation states may be initially formed, but then disproportionate in a manner like what I gave in my original answer. If you want to go deeper on this, I am not your man. I urge you to post another question about this specific issue and let a bona fide inorganic chemist respond.